# 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) error at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, runtime-error

I was trying to run my program in windows 8 machine and it's giving me this error at runtime (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). I don't experience any problem when I run it on a machine with windows 7 installed.

Here are the details (inner exception) :

```
 System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233079
 Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for    details.  The error is: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
Source=PayrollSystem
StackTrace:
   at PayrollSystem.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
   at PayrollSystem.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_frmMain()
   at PayrollSystem.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in \\Acc4-22\hideki programs\PayrollSystem_Program\PayrollSystem\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at PayrollSystem.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   HResult=-2147221164
   Message=Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   Source=System.Windows.Forms
   ErrorCode=-2147221164
   StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
        at PayrollSystem.frmMain.InitializeComponent() in \\Acc4-22\hideki programs\PayrollSystem_Program\PayrollSystem\FrmMain.Designer.vb:line 522
        at PayrollSystem.frmMain..ctor()
   InnerException:
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The error and call stack is indicative of an OLE or ActiveX control that your `PayrollSystem.frmMain` depends on, but it is not installed.  As to what component it wants to instantiate, there's not enough to go on.

And judging from the callstack, the only way to know is to actually look at the code in `frmMain.InitializeComponent` and/or look at the form's resource file to see what you have embedded there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to dig deep what ActiveX is missing because I'm pretty sure all prerequisite programs are present/installed since a similar program that uses the same resources works perfectly right, or I could be just overlooking some things.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in frmMain.InitializeComponent() and at line 522 of FrmMain.Desigener.vb.  Something in there is failing to initialize.